# How to pass the data to view in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Suppose i have a controller called home like this

```
class Home extends CI_Controller{


    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        //load the settings model
        $this->load->Model('settings_model');

        //get the all settings and store it into a variable
        $siteSettings = $this->settings_model->SiteSettings();


        //how to pass the data to view
        $data['site'] = $siteSettings;
    }

    public function index()
    {
        //some code and pass the value to view
        $data["some_item"] = "some value";

        //Load the view
        $this->load->view("home",$data);
    }

    public function SomeMethod1()
    {
        //some code and pass the value to view
        $data["some_item"] = "some value";

        //Load the view
        $this->load->view("home",$data);
    }


    public function SomeMethod2()
    {
        //some code and pass the value to view
        $data["some_item"] = "some value";

        //Load the view
        $this->load->view("home",$data);
    }


}
```

But my problem is i want to pass **$siteSettings** to my each method. I don't want to fetch the data every time from **settings_model** for my different method of home controller.  I just want to get the data from database on **__construct()** and pass the value to each method when i call the different method.

How can i achieve this? Should I use a public variable and store the fetched data to this variable and call the variable from different method?

Comment: is `$siteSettings` is array or one element??

Comment: $siteSettings is an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set that in session. and can access all over the project.

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->session->unset_userdata('site'); # unset on each and every time

    $this->load->Model('settings_model');
    $siteSettings = $this->settings_model->SiteSettings();

    $this->session->set_userdata('site', $siteSettings);  # Set after end of __construct
}
```

Or do like this

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->Model('settings_model');
    $this->data['site']  = $this->settings_model->SiteSettings();
}
```

**In function**

```
$this->load->view("name",$this->data);
```

Comment: I thought about this but is there another way by I can achieve this?

Comment: as your code `$data['site']` is passing any data or not??

Comment: yes. By this method ($this->settings_model->SiteSettings();) I extract the data from database and store it into this variable called $siteSettings

Comment: Now it working fine. Thanks bro for your help. Accepted.